# I have ubuntu on my laptop already and would like to duel boot Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, lvm

I have recently installed a new SSD and put Ubuntu 14.04 on it. I would like to duel boot with Windows, but I cannot figure out how to partition the hard drive. I am pretty new to linux but have tried using GParted and KVPM. However, neither seems to want to let me resize the largest partition and make it unallocated so I will have room to make a partition large enough to install Windows.

Comment: Did you read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot ?

Answer (score 1):

For beginners, like me, it's best to install Windows first and then Ubuntu because, so far I know, more recent Windows versions override installed boot info. After Windows installation, boot from Ubuntu bootable DVD/USB. During Ubuntu installation, you should get a window regarding boot-loader with one option saying something like  *install Ubuntu alongside other Operating Systems*. Selecting this option will let dual boot. After both installations are complete, default boot will be Ubuntu; it can be changed from the BIOS.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot